# Multiple FizzBuzz with input from file

Tags: java

I made a fizzbuzz program in Java 7 I'd like reviewed.

Given an input file with three numbers in each line, `fizz`, `buzz`, and `count`:

```
3 5 10
2 7 15
```

The output, for each line, should be the numbers from 1 to `count`, except that multiples of `fizz` are replaced with `"F"`, multiples of `buzz` are replaced by `"B"`, and multiples of both with `"FB"`:

```
1 2 F 4 B F 7 8 F B
1 F 3 F 5 F B F 9 F 11 F 13 FB 15
```

The code, in Java 7:

```
package com.codeeval.fizzbuzz;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String path = args[0];
        List<String> lines = getFileLines(path);

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (String line : lines){
            int[] arguments = getFizzBuzzArguments(line);
            int x = arguments[0];
            int y = arguments[1];
            int n = arguments[2];

            String result = fizzBuzz(x, y, n);
            sb.append(result).append('\n');
        }

        System.out.println(sb);
    }

    public static String fizzBuzz(int x, int y, int n) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            boolean isX = (i % x == 0);
            boolean isY = (i % y == 0);
            String append;

            if (isX || isY) {
                if (isX && isY) { append = "FB"; }
                else if (isX) { append = "F"; }
                else { append = "B"; }
            } else { append = Integer.toString(i); }

            sb.append(append);
            if (i != n){ sb.append(' '); }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    private static List<String> getFileLines(String path) throws IOException {
        File file = new File(path);
        BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
        String line;
        while ((line = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
            line = line.trim();
            lines.add(line);
        }

        return lines;
    }

    private static int[] getFizzBuzzArguments(String line){
        String[] arguments = line.split(" ");
        return getArrayOfInts(arguments);
    }

    private static int[] getArrayOfInts(String[] strings){
        int[] ints = new int[strings.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < strings.length; i++){
            ints[i] = Integer.parseInt(strings[i]);
        }

        return ints;
    }
}
```

Comment: Related question that you might be interested in: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/77569/31562

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is well structured and quite easy to read and understand: this is a very good point about it.

However, there are some things that may be improved, but very few of them seem to be really critical.

#### main(arg)

Variables `int x`, `int y` and `int n` are treated separately, but indeed they are semantically related, because they describe a "FizzBuzz" to produce. A dedicated class may be created, for example:

```
public class FizzBuzz {

  private final int x;
  private final int y;
  private final int n;

  public FizzBuzz(int x, int y, int n) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.n = n;
  }
  // getters, if needed
}
```

Moreover, your `fizzBuzz` method may then go directly into this class, named something like `processInput()`. The loop in `main()` would look like this:

```
for (String line : lines) {
  int[] arguments = getFizzBuzzArguments(line);
  FizzBuzz fb = new FizzBuzz(arguments[0], arguments[1], arguments[2]);
  sb.append(fb.processInput()).append('\n');
}
```

`FizzBuzz` may also have a constructor taking directly the array of input data as argument.

#### fizzBuzz(args)

Three points concerning the modulo divisions and the booleans `isX` and `isY`.

First, the divisors (`x` or `y`) must be validated to be different from 0, if you want to avoid `ArithmeticException` .

Second, they should be extracted into a dedicated method, which is easier to read:

```
private static boolean isMultipleOf(int dividend, int divisor) {
  return dividend % divisor == 0;
}
```

Third, the booleans are named poorly. They'd better sound as `isFizz` and `isBuzz`: these are their meanings.

Finally, the conditionals can be simplified:

```
if (isFizz || isBuzz) {
  if (isFizz) {
    sb.append("F");
  }
  if (isBuzz) {
    sb.append("B");
  }
} else {
  sb.append(i);
}
```

#### getFileLines()

Since you underline that the code in Java 7, then its facilities should be used.

- Replace `File` with `java.nio.file.Path`.
- Use a `try-with-resources` block in order to close automatically the streams opened with `BufferedReader` and `FileReader`.

Comment: I find that a `FizzBuzz` class would be overkill here. It would only provide one method, and storage for the parameters to that method. That is better of as a static method instead. And a `isMultipleOf` method is also overkill, `a % b == 0` is very common to use and totally readable.

Comment: @Simon, I agree with your remarks, these items _are_ an overkill in this context, because the entire task is small enough. I suggested to introduce the class because it clearly separates the core logic of the program (`fizzBuzz` method) from other pieces, which are mostly input data reading and preparation of arguments. And the extraction of `isMultipleOf` is done in order to avoid the almost duplicated `(i % x == 0)` calls. Of course, they are very common to use.

Comment: If you would extract `isMultipleOf`, then you would have multiple `isMultipleOf` calls. `(i % x == 0)` really isn't any more code duplication than calling `isMultipleOf` multiple times.

Answer (score 2):

### Handling errors

You're not handling these possible errors:

- A filename argument is not given
- The specified file does not exist.

You can handle them by checking the number of arguments:

```
if(args.length != 1) {
    System.err.println("Specify a filename as an argument");
    return;
}
```

and catching `FileNotFoundException`: (import it from `java.io`)

```
    try {
        String path = args[0];
        /* ... */
        System.out.println(sb);
    } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.err.println("The specified file was not found");
    }
```

You should also handle the case when a field in the file isn't a number (by catching `NumberFormatException`) or the number of fields isn't 3 (check it in `getFizzBuzzArguments` and throw in that case).

### Naming

I would rename `x`, `y` and `n` to `fizz`, `buzz` and `count` (and rename `isX` and `isY` to `isFizz` and `isBuzz`).

### Simplify conditionals

You can simplify the conditionals as @Antot suggested, and further simplify to:

```
if(isFizz) {
    sb.append("F");
}
if(isBuzz) {
    sb.append("B");
}
if(!isFizz && !isBuzz) {
    sb.append(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to concatenate the lines in `main` with a StringBuilder. Instead, inside the loop you can print each line right after you get the result from `fizzBuzz`:

```
System.out.println(result);
```

The output will be the same.

BTW if you are adding Strings without if/for conditions like `a + b` then it is optimized to StringBuilder by the compiler. So you don't need to use StringBuilder for simple cases of String concatenation.

It is over-optimization in this case.

Rest looks good.

Comment: Uh, no, that's wrong. It's recommended to use StringBuilder any time you're performing repeated, non-hard-coded appends.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes I have decompiled class files on Oracle's JDK 6 and JDK 7 to check that it actually happens. This is not a wild guess. Moreover when I search all new content also suggests that this happens. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18453458/string-builder-vs-string-concatenation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532461/stringbuilder-vs-string-concatenation-in-tostring-in-java. One of these refer to the Java specification in which it is stated that this optimization can be done by compiler. What are your references for the recommendation?

Comment: While this answer is not completely wrong, I find it a bit confusing and have chosen to downvote it primarily for that reason.

Comment: Hm, I can't find the line in the spec that says that it puts the StringBuilder in the narrowest scope possible, but I'm pretty sure it's there.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes Just for my future reference what would putting StringBuilder in the narrowest scope imply?

Comment: @AseemBansal I edited the first two lines to clarify your answer. Is this what you meant?

Comment: @Spike Yes. Thanks. In future will take care to remove any confusion with proper examples.